# implementation of the "Template method pattern" in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know that Objective-C doesn't support abstract classes but it's nonetheless OO language (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C). So I have several objects with the same methods except one, and I would like to follow the DRY principle and don't repeat a lot of the same code in several classes. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: A common superclass seems the right solution.

Comment: .... otherwise known as an **Abstract Superclass**.   See class clusters as one of the most widely used examples of such a pattern.

Comment: Thanks, it's what I expected to hear.

Comment: Can you give a high level overview of what your methods are? When you say "same methods" I'm assuming you mean that they do the exact same thing, not that they're identically named. Having identical names is not an issue, although it could get confusing to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I have several object with the same methods except one, so I would like to follow DRY principle and don't repeat a lot of the same code in one place.

I assume you mean "I have several *classes* with the same methods except one".

---

It depends on how formal you want to be about the whole thing. It all starts with a base class that has all the common methods. I will call that `@interface A : NSObject`.

Sub-classes of `A` will inherit from `A`

- `@interface A1 : A`
- `@interface A2 : A`

The sub-class that needs the unique method I will call `B`

- `@interface B : A`

You can test at run-time to see if objects of class A are able to perform that unique method.

```
A *a = ...
if ([a respondsToSelector:@selector(uniqueMethod)])
    [(id)a uniqueMethod];
```

This is a very informal method and may cause maintenance issues in the future if other classes start implementing the unique method.

Another option is to check for class membership.

```
A *a = ...
if ([a isKindOfClass:[B class]])
    [(B *)a uniqueMethod];
```

This is still informal, but provides better protection of future changes. It also limits future flexibility, because other instances of `A` may need to use the unique method in the future, but then must be refactored into sub-classes of `B`.

The formal way to do this is protocols. I will create protocols for `A` and `B` that I will call `AP` and `BP`. This changes the interface for `A` and `B`.

- `@interface A : NSObject <AP>`
- `@interface B : A <BP>`

Now the test becomes a matter for conformance.

```
A *a = ...
if ([a  conformsToProtocol:@protocol(BP)])
    [(id<BP>)a uniqueMethod];
```

This allows for protection and flexibility, but is more work to maintain when future changes are needed.

Hope that helps.